# Simple AWS Lambda function using node.js

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I'm trying to get a simple Lambda function running using node.js

```
function getVolumeNameTag(volumeId)
{
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var ec2 = new AWS.EC2();
var vol = ec2.describeVolume(volumeId)
...
}
```

How do I get the tag collection of the volume to find the name tag value?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The function is `describeVolumes(params, callback)` (you are missing an s and using wrong parameters). It's described in more detail here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#describeVolumes-property

So you basically need to build a params object to define what volumes to list and then just grab all the information from the `data` object (there is a `Tags` attribute (Array) for every returned volume) handed over to your callback function.

If you do not want to enter the callback hell have a look at https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/compute/node-js-8-10-runtime-now-available-in-aws-lambda/ to see how to do the same using Promises.